# Delete rows with a matching column - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am not sure what to title this, so feel free to edit it if you have a better one.

I currently have the following table in my database (It has many more rows than this):

```
|-----------------|
|Account |Group ID|
|--------|--------|
|HappyDy |  5532  |
|HDayGrp |  2212  |
|Yuyuyu  |  5532  |
|awesome |  4422  |
```

I want to delete all columns that have a Group ID (`group_id`) of "5532" using a MySQL command within PHP MyAdmin. Is there a MySQL command that can delete all rows with a Group ID of "5532"?

What I want the table to look like after the command is run:

```
|-----------------|
|Account |Group ID|
|--------|--------|
|HDayGrp |  2212  |
|awesome |  4422  |
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the description of the `DELETE` query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DELETE FROM <your_table> WHERE group_id = 5532`

(not sure what's the actual column name for "Group ID" but assumed `group_id`).

[MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html)